# Blender Viewport Shading mode Is showing a blurred object

Tags: materials, shaders

I can't figure out what I'm missing. Stepped away from Blender for a few months and now I opened a new general scene and went right to Viewport Shading and the object is blurred. Notice that you can see through,like it's transparent, the orange framing of the object. I tried this in 2.83 and also a new install of 3.31.  Touched nothing after opening Blender but just clicked on the Viewport Shading icon on the top right.

Edit: Maybe I should say what I'm expecting to see. An opaque grey box. The default scene has a bulb above it and this is the same PC I used in the past.

Attached is the opening screen I see after clicking Viewport Shading:

[image: Example Viewport Shading blurry object]

Comment: That looks like a graphics card driver problem. Have you tried updating it?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my Radeon Driver didn't auto update. Thanks @John Eason for the solution! After upgrading the Video Card driver, and rebooting it functioned correctly.